# How Do I relate and combine bar chart with bubble chart in D3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts

I want to use D3 for generating charts from JSON files. How do I combine/relate bar chart and bubble chart so when you click on either it should provide you details of both charts in a legend.

The each bubble must be below and center of the each bar. It must share x-axis of bar charts.

There are two different data sources for them.

No. of bars = No. of bubbles

Comment: Do you have anything to show such as sample data and  any code which you have tried.

Comment: you can check my demo here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doQrwp , I want to combine these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the xscale

```
var xScale =  d3.scale.ordinal() .domain( d3.range(dataset.length))
                    .rangePoints([0, w-50]);
```

This same scale is shared while drawing bar as well as circles.

[I have changed your codepen code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPdKQq)

Below is the complete code after change

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d,i) {
    //return i * (w / dataset.length);
   return xScale(i) ;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 10);
  })
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 10;
  })
  .attr("fill","#d38e71");

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  //.data(dataset)
.data(num)
  .enter()
.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://google.com")
.attr("xlink:title",function(d){
  return "No. of campagins sent - "+d;

})
.attr("target","_blank")
  .append("circle");

circles.attr("cx", function(d,i) {
 /*  return  i* (wB / dataset.length)+(wB / dataset.length)/2-2;*/
  return (xScale(i) + barWidth/2);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return hB-35;
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return rScale(d);
  })
```

Note the following code for bar

```
 .attr("x", function(d,i) {
    //return i * (w / dataset.length);
   return xScale(i) ;
  })
```

Note the following code for circles.

```
circles.attr("cx", function(d,i) {
 /*  return  i* (wB / dataset.length)+(wB / dataset.length)/2-2;*/
  return (xScale(i) + barWidth/2);
  })
```

**One suggestion**

Width of the bar is set via this statement (w / dataset.length - barPadding) This can be stored in a variable. So it will not calculate for each member in the chart.

Comment: Appreciate @ganesh but It does not relate/combine two charts!

Comment: I have updated the codepen. Check mouseovering on bars. Same technique can be implemented for circles.

Comment: Wow! man that's great! Is there any possibility to hover both bar and circle...so user can understand that - the bar is related to the particular circle ?

Comment: Updated the code. Please voteup and select as answer if it helped.

Comment: I want to upvote, but need 15 reputation. btw, Ganesh you did not get my question. Whenever you mouse over either on circle or bar, both must hover.

Comment: Ok I understood. Let me try.

Comment: Heya Ganesh, just found the solution. replace STROKE with FILL. :-) can you make this simple...no transition.hide and show only....Thanks for your help man...keep this attitude.